# How to Use Bind Variables in SQL Queries Run via RStudio

Tags: sql, r, oracle

To streamline my processes, I’m exploring RStudio’s “SQL Source” script functionality to preview the results of SQL queries. (To be clear, I’m trying to run raw SQL queries in RStudio via a .SQL script, using the DBI package and the previewSql function. More details [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008667993-Comment-Headers-in-RStudio-Sources?).)

When I test run SQL queries in the TOAD IDE, I commonly use bind variables. For example, here is a basic example of a SQL query with bind variables:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA
WHERE DATE BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE
```

In TOAD, when SQL queries with bind variables are run, a dialog box automatically opens that allows me to quickly define the values of the bind variables (e.g. `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`). This a convenient feature of TOAD that I commonly use, when I’m testing different cases for new SQL queries.

Is there a way to preview raw SQL queries in RStudio, with their bind variables intact?

By the way, I have run SQL queries before with R variables, replacing the SQL bind variables. This alternate method is run in a .R script, using functions from the `DBI` and `ROracle` package. For example, I would define the following objects: `START_DATE`, `END_DATE`, `SQL_QUERY_STRING`, and `SQL_RESULTS` as such:

```
START_DATE <- "'01-jan-2020'"
END_DATE <- "'31-jan-2020'"

SQL_QUERY_STRING <- paste("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE DATE BETWEEN", START_DATE, "AND", END_DATE)

SQL_RESULTS <- dbGetQuery(con, SQL_QUERY_STRING)
```

The method for querying a Oracle database using SQL in the RStudio IDE that I defined above works, but it’s not ideal when I’m at the beginning stages of writing and testing a more complex SQL query. Ultimately, I’d like to know if there’s a more efficient method for running SQL queries in RStudio, while maintaining the convenience of using SQL bind variables.

Comment: BTW, what you in your second code block is against best practices, and prone to SQL injection (either intentional/malevolent or accidental). While what you've done is safe-enough, when you start doing things more programmatically, this method will not survive. See https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for sharing the article, regarding the best practices for running SQL queries safely. It was very helpful! By the way, for others with a similar question, after investigating some more, it appears that the functionality to preview SQL query results for parameterized queries has not yet been implemented in RStudio: https://community.rstudio.com/t/preview-sql-query-results-for-parametrized-queries/29796/2

Comment: There is another option for this via rmarkdown variables and glue_sql, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832425/10527496 or here https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-multiple-r-variables-in-sql-chunk/2940/14